# Creating a singly linked list that contains the numbers within a given range of a BST

Tags: c, linked-list, range, binary-search-tree

I'm interested in finding all the integers within a given range that are in a `BST`. I'm wondering how would I go about doing this if the BST is created with nodes and thus I'd have to be using singly linked lists. The order of items in the linked list that is returned doesn't matter.

For example consider the Tree shown below,

[image]

The range is [6, 13], then the list should include 6->7->8->10->13 or 13->10->8->7->6. As I said, order doesn't matter in the returned list.

Also, the run-time constraint is O(n) where n is the number of nodes in the tree.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note, shouldn't it be 6->7->8->10->13? ... Lemme think about the answer of how in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this just with using 2 stacks...

Let's start with 2 stacks, 1 is simple todo stack (e.g. containing nodes you should visit), another one is stack with the results.

Start with root node, if node is in range, push it on results stack, and push both children to todo stack. If it's outside of range, 2 cases might occur:
1.) It's less than smallest value in our range -> push it's right child on todo stack
2.) It's greater than largest value in our range -> pus it's left child on todo stack

Okay so let's create this into some useful algorithm:

```
List<BSTNode*> FindAllInRange(BSTNode* root, int low, int high)
{
    Stack<BSTNode*> todo;              //< Todo stack
    Stack<BSTNode*> results;           //< Results stack

    // Start with root node
    todo.push(root);

    // While we have nodes to process
    while(todo.size() > 0)
    {
        // Get top node, and pop it from stack
        BSTNode* curr = todo.top();
        todo.pop();

        // If its value is less than the lowest value in range
        if(curr->value < low)
        {
            // Push right children if exists (as it may be higher than lowest value in range)
            if(node->right)
                todo.push(node->right);
        }
        // If its value is greater than the highest value in range
        else if(curr->value > high)
        {
            // Push left children if exists (as it may be lower than highest value in range)
            if(node->left)
                todo.push(node->left);
        }
        // Otherwise (we're in range)
        else
        {
            // Push current node to results stack
            results.push(curr);

            // If right node exists, push it on todo stack
            if(node->right)
                todo.push(node->right);

            // If left node exists, push it on todo stack
            if(node->left)
                todo.push(node->left);
        }
    }

    // Now you just have to convert the stack to list (and possibly sort it, reverse sort it, ...)
    return results.ConvertToList();
}
```

Note that this is just pseudo-code in C++ like language.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I was thinking of using recursion (which I don't think is optimal since I'm using C especially if the tree is huge).

Comment: Recursion  will not change the time complexity. But you indeed can run into stack overflow with it in extreme cases. However, this algorithm might have one problem. You said the order in output does not matter. In your example, however, answers are sorted, both. Now, if you need to maintain order, this algorithm will not pass time constraint. You will get results scattered and sorting it will take O(N log N). Otherwise it's modified [Bredth-first Graph Travesal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal#Breadth-first_search). Good for avoiding recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I you have basic knowledge on BST, you should be familiar that retrieving a sorted set of element from the tree is actually very trivial. If you are familiar with `LVR`/`RVL` traversing you can skip to "the answer".

**Recurrently traversing the tree:**

Traversing the tree is usually described as a combination of three letters `LVR`. `L` is left. `R` is right. `V` means visit.

This describes patter which you follow when traversing the tree. `L` means you ascend tree down to the left node if it exists. `R` for right. `V` means some operation on the current node like print. It uses recurrence!. It's quite important.

Now. How to get sorted set. It's simple `LVR` when visit means print or push.

**Example - a complete walk through:**

```
 (8) You start in root. `L` - go left. 
  (3) You are in (3). You go `LVR` for this node again - recurrence. `L`
    (1) You are in (1). Now *again* `LVR`.
    However there is no left node so we go to `V` - visit/print 1. Now `R` - no right node. End. By recurrence we go back to 3.
  (3) - We're done with `L`. We do `V`. Print 3.
  (3) - `R`.
    (6) You are in (6) - `LVR` again. 'L'
      (4) You are in (4) - `L` does not exists. Print 4. `R` does not exist. Back one level.
    (6) - `V`. Print 6.
    (6) - `R`.
      You are in (7) - `L` does not exists. Print 7. `R` does not exist. Back one level.
    (6) - `LVR` Done. Back one level.
  (3) - `LVR` Done. Back one level.
(8) - `R`.
  (10) You are in 10. `L` Does not exist.
  (10) `V`. Print 10.
  (10) `R`.
    (14) You are in 14.
    (14) `L`.
      (13) You are in 13. `L` does not exists. Print 14. `R` does not exist. Back one level.
    (14) `V`. Print 14.
    (14) `R`. Does not exist. Back one level.
  (10) Done with `R`. Back one level.
(8) Done with `R`. Back one level.
Haha we were on root node so we are done.
```

If you will follow prints. It will turn out you printed whole set in order lowest to highest. `RVL` pattern would do similar but since you go right 1st you will visit Right most nodes first thus the order would be descending. Since there is no magic and you visit each node exactly once, the time complexity is `O(n)`.

**The answer:**

Easy way. Do a normal `LVR` traverse. But print numbers only if it fits the range.
  Little harder but better average and extreme cases. Find the starting node. Then start traversing and on each visit compare only versus upper bound and stop when node data exceeds it.

Of course instead of printing you can use stack or something else (like list) you want to store elements in sorted order.

Comment: I was thinking of using this method except I was confused with the way I'd store the elements. I figured it out though.

Comment: It's easy if you pass down a reference to container or use a global one. Like I said, during visit step you can use anything you find suitable. I think this is the simplest algorithm, as long as you understand recurrence and tree travesing. Also if your tree is not bidirectional you will have troubles avoiding recurrence. I.e. you need to remember which node you came from or where to go next. As long as you want the output sorted, that is.